# Feeding input values to dpkg-reconfigure in a non-interactive way

Tags: dpkg

I would like to configure ubuntu package via dpkg-reconfigure with all the values supplied via non-interactive mode (in the script).

In fact my case is firebird confiiguration (http://www.firebirdsql.org/manual/ubusetup.html), that when using command:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure firebird2.5-superclassic -freadline
```

asks me for the 2 values, where answers would be 'Y' and 'newpwd' .

Sample output looks like this:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure firebird2.5-superclassic -freadline
 * Firebird 2.5 superclassic server not running
Configuring firebird2.5-superclassic
------------------------------------

Accept if you want Firebird server to start automatically.

If you only need the Firebird client and there are no databases that will be served by this host, decline.

Enable Firebird server? Y


Password for firebird 2.5
-------------------------

Firebird has a special user named SYSDBA, which is the user that has access to all databases. SYSDBA can also create new databases and users. Because of this, it 
is necessary to secure SYSDBA with a password.

The password is stored in /etc/firebird/2.5/SYSDBA.password (readable only by root). You may modify it there (don't forget to update the security database too, 
using the gsec utility), or you may use dpkg-reconfigure to update both.

To keep your existing password, leave this blank.

Password for SYSDBA: 


 * Starting Firebird 2.5 superclassic server...
   ...done.
 * Firebird 2.5 superclassic server already running
```

I've tried `here strings` via bash script like this:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure firebird2.5-superclassic -f readline << EOF
Y
newpwd
EOF
```

However this didn't work for some reason and it asked for the values to be supplied.

Any ideas how to feed the required values to script?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can always use the [expect language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect) to automate interaction with a process that expects its input on a `tty`. I haven't really used it before so I can't really add code here but yours is a typical use case.

**UPDATE:**

[Peter Butkovic] I consider pointing me to `expect` as a right direction, this script I ended with:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn dpkg-reconfigure firebird2.5-superclassic -freadline
expect "Enable Firebird server?"
send "Y\r"

expect "Password for SYSDBA:"
send "newpwd\r"

# done
expect eof
```

Comment: thanks for pointing me the right direction. I consider this answer as correct one as it was the easy to implement solution.

Comment: I would be wary of the possibility of i18n issues, but for "home use" this seems safe.

Answer (score 26):

Debian packages use [debconf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debconf_%28software_package%29) to collect installation-time settings. Debconf supports multiple frontends to prompt the user for values. The `-f` option to `dpkg-reconfigure` selects which debconf frontend to use.

The `readline` frontend is designed for interactive use. Don't use it in an automatic script.

If the default values are fine, then simply use the `noninteractive` frontend.

If you want to supply different values, you have two options. You can stick with the `noninteractive` frontend, and [preseed the debconf database](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man7/debconf.7.html#contenttoc7). The easiest way to do this is to install the package on one machine and configure it interactively, then extract the relevant parts from `/var/cache/debconf/config.dat` and supply this file to debconf:

```
DEBCONF_DB_OVERRIDE='File {/path/to/config.dat}' dpkg-reconfigure -fnoninteractive firebird2.5-superclassic
```

Another method is to use the `editor` frontend, and set the environment variable `VISUAL` (or `EDITOR`, but `VISUAL` has precedence over `EDITOR` if it is set) to a program that takes a file containing the current settings as an argument, and overwrites that file with the settings you want.

Comment: No need to parse `/var/cache/debconf/config.dat` yourself. You can use `debconf-get-selections` from the `debconf-utils` package. See [this](http://www.zacks.eu/automating-installations-with-debconf-preseeding/) for example.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure if preseeding is the right fit here. We're talking about running `dpkg-reconfigure`, which I'm guessing the OP wants to automate because he'll be doing it frequently.

Comment: thanks for hints. decided to go for expect script. didn't investigate deeper here.

Comment: @JosephR. Indeed, `debconf-get-selections` is likely to be useful here. If Peter wants to do this often with different values, he should generate a `config.dat` dynamically (it's a simple format). This is easier than `expect`. `expect` is the path of desperation. For example, it'll break down if a new version of the package introduces a new question (or else you need a far more sophisticated script).

Comment: @cjohnson318 Not sure which link you're referring to. I tried both links in the answer and they both work on my end.

Comment: @JosephR. The link in the first comment on this answer doesn't work for me. It takes me to a blog, but the post seems to have moved.

Answer (score 20):

Use `debconf-set-selections` command to insert new values into the debconf database (`/var/cache/debconf/config.dat`).

---

[Eli answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/158201/21471) wasn't clear for me, so I'll explain it step by step.

The first thing to do is to install package interactively and get the chosen selections by (change `firebird` to your package name):

```
sudo debconf-get-selections | grep ^firebird
```

or:

```
grep -C2 firebird /var/cache/debconf/config.dat
```

Then pre-seed the debconf database with answers by `debconf-set-selections`, for example:

```
echo firebird2.5-superclassic shared/firebird/enabled boolean true | sudo debconf-set-selections -v
echo firebird2.5-superclassic shared/firebird/sysdba_password/new_password password foo | sudo debconf-set-selections -v
```

where syntax is:

```
echo foo-owner-package-name foo-template-name value-type value | debconf-set-selections
```

Here is another example for `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` package:

```
echo ttf-mscorefonts-installer msttcorefonts/accepted-mscorefonts-eula select true | sudo debconf-set-selections
```

<sup>Note: The input selections can be either from the standard input or the file.</sup>

Check: `man debconf-set-selections` for further info.

Note: If `debconf-get-selections` is not found, use

```
apt-get install debconf-utils
```

to install.

---

Alternative way is to use [Kickstart](https://askubuntu.com/a/25614/78223).

Comment: debconf-set-selections  doesn't seem to take effect in all cases, eg: exim.

Comment: debconf-set-selections does NOT run the configuration script built into the deb package you are changing.  It only sets the selections the package is asking for which is only the first part of it.  dpkg-reconfigure runs both parts.

Comment: This should be the correct answer for this question.

Comment: @fred I'm not sure I get it… should I run `printf %s\\t%s\\t%s\\t%s\\n keyboard-configuration keyboard-configuration/ctrl_alt_bksp boolean true | sudo debconf-set-selections -v` followed by `sudo dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive keyboard-configuration` ? Or is there something else to do in order to re-run the configuration script with the values that were just set? If I run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`, the preselected values in the text user interface are *NOT* the ones that were given to `debconf-set-selections`, so I guess those were ignored in non-interactive mode too.

Answer (score 6):

I've been poking around for about an hour just trying to condense the solution for this down to a one-liner and I finally found it: [debconf-set-selections](http://man.he.net/man1/debconf-set-selections)

```
echo "debconf debconf/frontend select noninteractive" | sudo debconf-set-selections
```

This will force debconf to use the defaults and not bug you. You can also set the configuration defaults for any Debian package, [see the manpage](http://man.he.net/man1/debconf-set-selections) for more info.

Comment: Isn't the same as `sudo dpkg-reconfigure debconf -f noninteractive` or `export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive`?

Comment: No, `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` allows to accept default answers without interaction. This allows to change those answers.

Answer (score 2):

My version of the [expect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect) solution to install the ArangoDB .deb using [pexpect](https://github.com/pexpect/pexpect)

```python
import pexpect
import os

os.environ['DEBIAN_FRONTEND']= 'readline'

child = pexpect.spawnu('dpkg -i arangodb3_3.6.2-1_amd64.deb')

child.expect('user:')
child.sendline('defg')
child.expect('user:')
child.sendline('defg')
child.expect("Automatically upgrade database files")
child.sendline("yes")
child.expect("Database storage engine")
child.sendline("1")
child.expect("Backup database files before upgrading")
child.sendline("no")
child.expect(pexpect.EOF)
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been attempting to do scripted reconfiguration of LDAP settings (ldap-auth-config package) using the debconf-get-selections/set-selections method mentioned above, only to find that this package ignores settings in debconf after initial installation. You can use debconf to pre-seed before install, but after install ldap-auth-config prefers to overwrite your debconf settings with whatever is set in the system config files it manages. Package pam-auth-config has the same behavior.

The EDITOR/VISUAL mechanism is also difficult to use in this case because ldap-auth-config invokes it multiple times for different sets of questions. It can be handled more easily with an expect script, or by directly modifying the system config files. So, it's not always easy to avoid falling back to expect!